# debugging Android NDK application problems

Tags: android-ndk

i had a problem in my native android application saying `libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x66f0001d (code=1), thread 30165 (xample.fft_test)`
which i think is a memory problem on the device(nexus 4).

So, i tried to debug the application to know the source of this problem.

In eclipse, i get `warning: Could not load shared library symbols for 94 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will retry eventurally.  Meanwhile, it is likely
that GDB is unable to debug shared library initializers
or resolve pending breakpoints after dlopen().`

what does that mean?

here's also the output of the allocation tracker in eclipse:

[image]

Comment: How are you compiling the code? With Cmake or with Android.mk?

Comment: Your Application.mk has flags:
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_OPTIM := debug
????

Comment: i have something like APP_OPTIM:=debug     APP_STL:=stlport_static

Comment: The warning means those libraries have not compiled with debug flags, and then, you have not debug info so you cannot debug. Maybe you can stop in breakpoints and follow step by step, but you cannot read in real time the value of the variables.

Comment: that's what i did, and you re right i couldn't read the real time values. Do you think  it is a problem in configuring NDK in eclipse or a device problem?

Answer (score 1):

If your application.mk has flags:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static 
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

You have a problem with the compilation´s flags.

The warning means those libraries have not compiled with debug flags, and then, you have not debug info so you cannot debug. Maybe you can stop in breakpoints and follow step by step, but you cannot read in real time the value of the variables.

So, to solve the problem, you must re-compile the libraries that you want to read variables with debug information flags. In Cmake I usually use flag -d or -gdwarf-4 to crosscompile in Android.

Comment: how to do that in eclipse?

Comment: Just add Application.mk in your jni folder, the same path as your Android.mk  Eclipse will launch your ndk-build to use the flags.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by using another phone.

I tested on a lot of phones. Finally, I find out that debug NDK on Nexus 6 is ok.

So I think maybe the issue is that the support for debugging NDK was removed on some phones.